# Are there any way to export Sonarlint report from Intellij?

Tags: java, spring-boot, static-analysis, code-analysis, sonarlint-intellij

I generated the Sonarlint report in Intellij. But there is no any options to export as document. Is it possible to export a report in Intellij?

Comment: SonarLint does not provide a way to export reports on purpose. You should use their SonarQube or SonarCloud solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **don't** think that the **Intellij currently supports that**.

You can try:
**SonarQube or PMD** - to generate code report.

In PMD you can export that to any file you want, forex .html.
SoarQube should have export options.

Have a nice day.